# How to add multiple times the same entity in a manyToMany association with Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my Badges Entity, I have this manytomany association:

```
<?php

class Badges
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Unidirectional - Many users have Many new Matches (OWNING SIDE)
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Event", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $match;
}
```

Which takes an event and associate it to this badge. Many badges can have many events. That's ok.

Now my problem is that a Badge can have several time the same event. And doctrine 2 Does NOT like that and throw out an error. Something like "This relation (Badge_id - Event_id ) already exist.

How do I fix that ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your relationship one more attribute `count` that will store number of duplicating pairs. And if record is already exist you can just increment count instead of trying to insert new row.

To define relationship with an attribute in Doctrine you need to define entity in the middle between your `Badge` and `Event` entities:

```
  +---------+          +---------+   
  |         |          |         |   
  |  Badge  |          |  Event  |   
  |         |          |         |   
  +--+------+          +------+--+   
     1                        1      
     |                        |      
     |   +---------------+    |      
     |   |               |    |      
     +-N-+  Badge_Event  +-N--+      
         |               |           
         +---------------+
```

In Badge_Event entity you can define your new attribute `count`.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I did look for a documentation about this, which seems to fix my problem, but I can't see anything related to a count attribute in a many to many association. Could you provide me a link please ? Sorry to ask this, but I did google it, and found nothing. I would expect it to be here : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

Comment: You can define relationship with an attribute only via middle Entity. I updated my answer to show you ER scheme for this case.